# Python 3.0 Classes and OOP basics, with UML model?

Tags: python, class, loops, math

I am trying to make a program that exercises my knowledge of classes and formatting / basic math within modules I create. The idea was to create a `Merchandise` data class (called `Merchandise.py`) and, in a separate file, an executable program named `store_merch.py` to test it. I know I'm supposed to model it after basic UML diagrams like so:

```
Merchandise

__item

__quantity

__cost

__init__(item,quantity,cost)

set_item(item)

set_quantity(quantity)

set_cost(cost)

get_item()

get_quantity()

get_cost()

get_inventory_value()

__str__()
```

I know that the `get_inventory_value()` method will calculate/print the value of the merchandise item in currency format, and the `__str()__` method will return a string showing all 3 attributes and the inventory value (quantity * cost).

**EDIT**: It seems there is some confusion as to what I am asking here, so I've highlighted the core concept of what I'm getting at below: (note, I am trying to stress using getter/setters). There are two programs here, the merchandise.py which has all the getters/setters and the second program asks for input from the user and runs the merchandise.py module

**For the `store_merch` program I want to:**

**create a `Merchandise` instance for 10 hammers costing $14.95 each.**

**create another `Merchandise` object for 6 necklaces costing $799.99 each.**

**run the `__str__` methods of both objects.**

**prompt the user for a new quantity for the hammer object, then change this attribute with the setter method.**

**prompt the user for a new cost for the necklace object, then change this attribute with the setter method.**

**verify the changes by running the `__str__` methods again.**

**display the inventory value for each object as well.**

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

**hammer, 10 @ $14.95**

**necklace, 6 @ $799.99**

**Enter new quantity for hardware 12**

**Enter new cost for jewelry 659**

**hammer, 12 @ $14.95**

**Inventory value: $179.40**

**necklace, 6 @ $659.00**

**Inventory value: $3,954.00**

The two programs I have so far are below:

```
 ## first program "merchandise.py" with getters/setters to use in next program:

class Merchandise:
    def __init__(self,item,quantity,cost):
        self.__item = item
        self.__quantity = quantity
        self.__cost = cost

    def set_item(self,item):
        self.__item = item

    def set_quantity(self,quantity):
        self.__quantity = quantity

    def set_cost(self,cost):
        self.__cost = cost

    def get_item(self):
        return self.__item

    def get_quantity(self):
        return self.__quantity

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.__cost

    def __str__(self):
        s = self.__item + ' ' + str(self.__quantity)
        s += ' @ ' + str(self.__cost)
        return s


## --------SEPARATE PROGRAM TO RUN MERCHANDISE MODULE BELOW----------

## merchandise input program
### import the merchandise module
import merchandise

def main():
    ### make a new merchandise? instance
    store_merchandise = merchandise.Merchandise('hammer',10,14.95)
    ### display status of merchandise object
    print(store_merchandise)

    ### change Item, Quantity, and Cost
    store_merchandise.set_item('necklaces')
    store_merchandise.set_quantity(6)
    store_merchandise.set_cost(799.99)
    ### display status of store merchandise object
    print(store_merchandise)

    item2 = input('Enter new quantity for hardware ') # prompt user for new quantity
    ### initiate another merchandise
    ### change Item, Quantity, and Cost
    store_merchandise.set_item('hammer')
    store_merchandise.set_quantity(item2)
    store_merchandise.set_cost(14.95)
    ### display status of store merchandise object
    print(store_merchandise)

    necklace2 = input('Enter new cost for necklaces ') # prompt user for new quantity
    ### initiate another merchandise
    ### change Item, Quantity, and Cost
    store_merchandise.set_item('necklace')
    store_merchandise.set_quantity(necklace2)
    store_merchandise.set_cost(659.00)
    ### display status of store merchandise object
    print(store_merchandise)


    ### add the new inventory value total and print the sum

    print(store_merchandise + format(store_merch.get_cost(), ',.2f'), sep='')

main()
```

Currently it only renames the hammer instance and it's attributes and prompts the user correctly, printing the new prices/quantities for hammers and necklaces but not the way I intend. **A friend of mine helped point out a few things I'm doing wrong but I'm honestly at a bit of a loss as how to create more instances and call previous ones, all while adding an attribute of each of them together and displaying the result:**

**1. You didn't create a second object for necklaces. You re-assigned the properties of the hardware object. you didn't use the inputs.
This...    store_merchandise.set_quantity(12)
Should be...    store_merchandise.set_quantity(item2)**

**2. In your input for the new quantity of hammers, you forgot to use the int() function.**

**3. The line that starts store_merch = is another culprit. You forgot to use merchandise.Merchandise as you did at the start of main. But anyway, you shouldn't be creating a new instance named store_merch. You should be using the store_merchandise object's setter for the quantity. Take it from there!**

Any and all help is appreciated! First question on here so I'm hoping I followed all the rules before posting!! (:

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: You don't need getters and setters in python, because you can use @property: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: I'm trying to get that sample output that's above my code, and I am aware of the property feature but this exercise is specifically to manage and edit a class module using the getters/setters as I clearly need review in getting them to work.

Comment: I'm extremely confused. I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: "class module" doesn't mean anything... And it seems that no one here clearly understand what your question is exactly.

Comment: That's ok all part of the process, I guess I have to learn better communication so you guys understand what I'm asking!

Comment: hammer, 10 @ $14.95
necklace, 6 @ $799.99
Enter new quantity for hardware 12
Enter new cost for jewelry 659
hammer, 12 @ $14.95
Inventory value: $179.40
necklace, 6 @ $659.00
Inventory value: $3,954.00 

All I'm really trying to do is create this sample out put above. I'd like to do it by creating two objects, hammer and necklace, with a quantity and price to start.

Comment: Then the user of the program should be prompted to enter a new quantity for the hammers, and a new price for the necklaces. the program would then display the price and quantity of the updated objects and add up the sum of their price, effectively the "inventory total". Does this help clarify what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @AshleyJae please edit your question instead of commenting. Also please try to turn your code into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not too sure what you're question is, but I know what your friend means by "you didn't create a second object for necklaces"

You initiated store_merchandise as a merchandise object, then continually use set_x(x) to change its property.

Instead, you should instantiate a new instance of the object by initiating another variable, not changing the original ones properties. This can be done in the same you initiated the first one, but using a different name.

```html
store_merchandise = merchandise.Merchandise('hammer',10,14.95) //initiate the first object properties 'hammer',12,14.95
store_merchandise2 = merchandise.Merchandise('necklaces',6,799.99) //initiate the second object with properties 'necklaces',6,799.99
```

you can then access these the same way as before, calling each one seperately when you need them. This way, you have two seperate instances of a Merchandise object rather than change a single instance.

Comment: thank you very much R Nar I did not realize i wasn't creating new instances of the object, this has been the most help yet :)